# How to use firestore TIMESTAMP to create time-stamp in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am getting the data like this
October 17, 2017 at 5:47:37 PM UTC+5:30
Now, how can i convert it to timestamp like 55773**998 ?

Comment: I have no idea why there timestamps looks like that... I just rather use Date.now().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove `at` and then convert it to new date.

```js
var date = " October 17, 2017 at 5:47:37 PM UTC+5:30";
var parsedDate = new Date(date.replace(/at/g, "")).getTime();
console.log(parsedDate);
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to import the Firebase Admin:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
```

Then save the Firestore timestamp:

```
const timestamp = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```